How to use key vault in Azur synapse for serverless pool
i create the linker service azure synapse for serverless pool below is the image
and test connection is successfull 
give serverless pool name and database name manully
and i can preview the data
But when i used keyvalut then i am not able to preview the data and got this error
error message when i used key valut
basically i am try to copy the view from serverless pool to sql server using copy activity and work good when i pass and enter the serverless pool name and database name manully but as i used the key valut it show i have no access

To access the Serverless SQL pool in Synapse, you must have either the Synapse Administrator role or the Synapse SQL Administrator role.
The below are the steps you can follow:
Step 1:
In synapse workspace Manage> Access Control.

Step 2:
Add Role


Reference:
Synapse RBAC Roles
Azure Synapse Studio ServerLess SQL Pool Access Error
